# Sorting through list of lists?

Tags: python, list, indexing, default

So I have a list of lists:

nums = [[98, 90, 91], [46, 76, 62], [85, 90, 83], [77, 79, 81]]

and I want to sort through them. When a number in a list(mini-lists) of the

list(main list) is lower than a default I give in the argument, the function

will return a list with either true or false for every list in the list.

Example: [True, False, True, True]

Here is my code so far:

```
def all_passing(nums, grade = 70):
 new = [] 
 for l in nums:
    boo = True
    for x in l:
       if x <= grade:
          boo == False
          new.append(boo)
 return new
```

Every time I run the code, my output is an empty list.

**Edit: I fixed some things and now I'm getting closer to my solution, but it is returning True or 
False for EVERY value in the list of lists. How do I make it so that the it only returns True or 
False for the individual lists. 
Example: [98, 90, 91] would be set to True. [46, 76, 62] would be set to False 
since an x in the list is lower than 70. Same thing for the other lists.**

**Edit: I got to work, I indented the append line to the same indentation of the second for loop, now I understand how it works. Thank you!!!**

Comment: Just to clarify, this is in python, right?

Comment: Yes, I am using python. Sorry about that.

Comment: You should add that as a tag. It would have made it more likely for people to read your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems in your code are:

1. `boo == False` is testing whether or not boo is equal to false. Change this to `boo = False` to set `boo` to `False`
2. `new.append(boo)` is only called if `x <= grade`. Move that to outside both the `if` statement and `for x in l`

Your final code should be:

```
def all_passing(nums, grade = 70):
    new = [] 
    for l in nums:
        boo = True
        for x in l:
            if x <= grade:
                boo = False
        new.append(boo)
    return new
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm getting closer! Could you take a look at my edit? Thanks again!

Comment: @BongWater Do you mean your first edit or second edit?

Comment: I meant the first one but its okay, I figured it out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Shortest I could do:

```
def all_passing(nums, grade = 70):
    return [ [ True if elel > grade else False for elel in el ] for el in nums ]
```

But if you want it to return only one list (I'm not sure if I get what you asked) with a True of False dedending on the results of the mini-lists, then I would do

```
def all_passing(nums, grade = 70):
    ans = [ [ True if elel > grade else False for elel in el ] for el in nums ]
    return [ False if False in el else True for el in ans ]
```

The second example gave me `[True, False, True, True]`, similar to what you expected.

Comment: This is list comprehension right? Can you explain to me how it works?

Comment: I believe the first bit of code is what the OP wanted.  The inner list comprehension does this:    return `True` for every element `elel` of the nested list `el` -- `if elel > grade`... otherwise return `False`.  This will build a list of `True` and `False` for each nested list.  The outer list comprehension iterates over all of the nested list, and builds a list of lists of `True` and `False`.    NOTE: for small lists like the OP has provided, this solution will probably be slower than nested `for` loops.